# React Native -- 'Unsplash' API Error: not implemented

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

I'm trying to do a image application in **React Native** with **Unsplash** API

The error appear when I try to access the information inside the API, before that, with the calling of the API I don't have any trouble.

I'm new in the world of **React Native** and I see that the errors are very difficult to read.

So here its the code, how I said, when I try to call the API the app crash:

```
 import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
 import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
 import { createApi } from 'unsplash-js';
 import fetch from 'node-fetch';
 global.fetch = fetch;


 export default function App() {
 const unsplash = createApi({
 accessKey: 'MY_ACCESS_KEY',
 fetch: fetch,
 });

 unsplash.photos.get(
 { photoId: '123' },
 // `fetch` options to be sent only with _this_ request
 { headers: { 'X-Custom-Header-2': 'bar' } },
 );
 console.log(unsplash)

 return (
 <View style={styles.container}>
   <Text>Holaaaa!</Text>
   <StatusBar style="auto" />
 </View>
 );
 }

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
 flex: 1,
 backgroundColor: '#fff',
 alignItems: 'center',
 justifyContent: 'center',
 },
 });
```

I read that the error might be for the global URL, because in the render it appear this

```
get pathname()
{ throw new Error("not implemented")}
```

and in the console (this is what I was saying of the difficult of the errors)

> Error: not implemented
>
> This error is located at:
> in App (created by ExpoRoot)
> in ExpoRoot
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by AppContainer)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by AppContainer)
> in AppContainer
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:149:8 in registerError
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:60:8 in errorImpl
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:34:4 in console.error
> at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:172:19 in handleException
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ReactFiberErrorDialog.js:43:2 in showErrorDialog
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-
> dev.js:15792:34 in logCapturedError
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-
> dev.js:15884:20 in update.callback
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-
> dev.js:7199:2 in callCallback
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-
> dev.js:7220:20 in commitUpdateQueue
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-
> dev.js:16632:25 in commitLifeCycles
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-
> dev.js:19216:22 in commitLayoutEffects
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. install  `react-native-url-polyfill/auto`
2. add `import 'react-native-url-polyfill/auto';` in the file index.js of project.

Just in case, install the library `whatwg-fetch` and import it into the same file where is `node-fetch`.

That worked out for me.